# How would I go about analyzing the formal complexity of this algorithm under Big Theta Θ notation?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I’m needing some help understanding algorithm analysis using [Big Theta Θ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) notation:

> Big *O* is the most commonly used asymptotic notation for comparing functions, although in many cases Big *O* may be replaced with Big Theta Θ for asymptotically tighter bounds.

How would I analyze this algorithm step by step? I know the final answer is ϴ(*n*²), but I’m having trouble seeing it. Any help would be appreciated.

You may assume for simplicity that *n* = 2*k*, for some positive integer *k*.

```
 int a = 0;
 int i = n * n;
 while (i > 0) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          a++; 
      }
      i = i/2;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ignore the fact that `i = n * n` for a minute and just consider the algorithm

```
while(i > 0)
{
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
       { a++; }
    i=i/2;
}
```

`i = i/2` says `i` divides by `2`, rounding down. In the worst case, there will be no rounding down. This happens if `i` is a power of `2`. Let's suppose `i == 16`. The values of `i` are then `16, 8, 4, 2, 1`. The `for` loop has `i` iterations, so the total number of times `a++;` gets executed is `16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 31`. In general if `i` is a power of `2`, `a++;` happens `2i - 1` times. From an asymptotic point of view the complexity is therefore linear in `i`, or `O(i)`.

Since `i == n^2`, the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

To prove it's Theta(n^2) we have to prove that the run time is always more than a fixed multiple of n^2. But in this case we can see that the number of times `a++` happens is more than 1 times `n^2` because `n^2` is the first value of `i`.

Comment: You've shown it's O(n^2), but to prove Theta(n^2) you must also show that the run time (for large n) is bounded below by a multiple of n^2. It's fairly obvious since the first time the j-loop is executed it'll loop n^2 times.

Comment: @Anonymous You're right. I always get O, Theta and Omega mixed up. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the outer loop controls the value of `i`. Each time the loop goes through, `i` is divided by two. The initial values of the loop are then `i`, `i/2`, `i/4`...

The inner loop contains `i` computations. If you sum this, you get `i + i/2 + i/4 + i/8 + i/16 + ... <= 2 * i`. (`<=` because we are using integer division which is always `<=` the true value)

So the total number of calculations `<= i == 2 * n * n`.

We can also see that the number of calculations `>= i = n*n`. Since it is bounded above and below by `n*n` and `2*n*n`, it is `Big Theta(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int a = 0, i=n*n;
 while(i > 0)
 {
      for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
         { a++; }
      i=i/2;
 }
```

How many times are you executing the for loop:

first time throught the while loop, `i = n^2`

2nd time, `i/2 = (n2)/2`

3rd, `(n2)/4`

thus suming them up gives `n^2 + n^2/2 + n^2/4 + ....`

which tends towards `2n^2 = O(n^2)` as Big O notation is only concerned about the order of n

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of times `a` gets incremented:

```
n^2 on the first iteration
+
n^2 / 2 on the second iteration
+
...
+
n^2 / 2^k on the (k+1)-th iteration
```

We have that `k = log(n^2) = 2*log(n)`, because we divide by `2` at each step.

So we have the sum of a geometric progression with first term `n^2`, ratio `1/2` and `2*log(n)` terms, or to make things easier, first term `1` and ratio `2`:

```
S = O(2^(2*log(n))) = O([2^log(n)]^2) = O(n^2)

=> The entire algorithm is BigTheta(n^2)
```